# Double click on table row and insert value in input field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this Angular table with row select:

```
<div class="ag-root-wrapper-body ag-layout-normal ag-focus-managed" ref="rootWrapperBody"><div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-top" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <!--AG-GRID-COMP--><div class="ag-root ag-unselectable ag-layout-normal" role="grid" unselectable="on" ref="gridPanel" aria-rowcount="2" aria-colcount="4">
        <!--AG-HEADER-ROOT--><div class="ag-header ag-focus-managed ag-pivot-off" role="presentation" ref="headerRoot" unselectable="on" style="height: 26px; min-height: 26px;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedLeftHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
            <div class="ag-header-viewport" ref="eHeaderViewport" role="presentation">
                <div class="ag-header-container" ref="eHeaderContainer" role="rowgroup" style="width: 700px; transform: translateX(0px);"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 700px;"><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="1" col-id="operationCodeName" style="width: 300px; left: 0px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-242-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Operation Code</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="2" col-id="accessorialExpectedAmount" style="width: 150px; left: 300px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-245-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Expected</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="3" col-id="accessorialActualAmount" style="width: 150px; left: 450px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-248-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Actual</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="4" col-id="accessorialExpectedUOMShortName" style="width: 100px; left: 600px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-261-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">UOM</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedRightHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-floating-top" ref="eTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eLeftTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-top-viewport" ref="eTopViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <div class="ag-floating-top-container" ref="eTopContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 700px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eRightTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-top-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eTopFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-body-viewport ag-layout-normal ag-row-no-animation" ref="eBodyViewport" role="presentation">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eLeftContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="253" class="ag-row ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last ag-row-focus ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."></div></div>
            <div class="ag-center-cols-clipper" ref="eCenterColsClipper" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;">
                <div class="ag-center-cols-viewport" ref="eCenterViewport" role="presentation" style="height: calc(100% + 17px);">
                    <div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 700px; height: 50px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="253" class="ag-row ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last ag-row-focus ag-row-selected ag-row-not-inline-editing" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="263" col-id="accessorialExpectedUOMShortName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 600px;  ">m</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="254" col-id="operationCodeName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 300px; left: 0px;  ">Accessorial Charge</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="255" col-id="accessorialExpectedAmount" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus" style="width: 150px; left: 300px;  ">3.00000000</div><div tabindex="-1" id="ted-test" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="256" col-id="accessorialActualAmount" class="ag-cell ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-not-inline-editing" style="width: 150px; left: 450px;  ">NaN</div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eRightContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="253" class="ag-row ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last ag-row-focus ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."></div></div>
            <div class="ag-full-width-container" ref="eFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-floating-bottom" ref="eBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-bottom ag-hidden" ref="eLeftBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-bottom-viewport" ref="eBottomViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <div class="ag-floating-bottom-container" ref="eBottomContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 700px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-bottom ag-hidden" ref="eRightBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-bottom-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eBottomFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll" ref="eHorizontalScrollBody" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;">
            <div class="ag-horizontal-left-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eHorizontalLeftSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport" ref="eBodyHorizontalScrollViewport" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;">
                <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-container" ref="eBodyHorizontalScrollContainer" style="width: 700px; height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-horizontal-right-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eHorizontalRightSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!--AG-OVERLAY-WRAPPER--><div class="ag-overlay ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true" ref="overlayWrapper">
            <div class="ag-overlay-panel">
                <div class="ag-overlay-wrapper ag-layout-normal ag-overlay-no-rows-wrapper" ref="eOverlayWrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    
                <div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-bottom" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div></div>
```

(See he input field where I have `Nan` value)

When I double click in Nan value I get:

```
              <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-text-field-label"></div>
             <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-text-field-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-text-field-input" type="text" id="ag-285-input" aria-label="Input Editor">
                </div>
            </div></div></div></div></div>
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/hNvj56Pz

I use this code to double click on table row and insert a value into input filed:

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/......iv[3]"));
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.doubleClick(element).perform();
    
            Thread.sleep(3000);
    
            // Insert into Accessorial Tasks screen Actual value
            insertInputFieldByXPath(driver, "...../input",
                    "3");

protected void insertInputFieldByXPath(WebDriver driver, String input_id, String value){
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(input_id)));
        webElement.clear();  // First we delete the old value in case if this is a spinner
        webElement.sendKeys(value);
    }
```

When I double click with Selenium the table row becomes input field. But when I try to enter some value the id is not found because the id is dynamically generated.

How I can get the parent of the of the input filed and insert value?

Do you know how this issue can be solved?

Comment: The id is dynamically generated, but what about the name?

Comment: Also, what does the id look like please? Is there a part of it that doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

When the dom updates, you need to get the element again, which I don't think doubleClick() does. I would try using a single click twice, get the new input element and then use send keys to send the text.